# How to add css and js in php 7 codeigniter 3.1.11?

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**  I know i need to add

```
<?php echo site_url ('path.css');?>">
```

**For css file and **

```
<?php echo site_url ('path.js');?">
```

**For js file, but actually dont know where in my code i need to add them and do i need to install jquery , If yes , how? can someone please help me how to complete this process? here is my html file  **

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
        <title>ASGB Ticketing Tool</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/image/favicon.png"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mystyle.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/datatables.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-cus navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand waves-light" href="#">
    <img src="assets/image/logo.png" />
  </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-mob-bar" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto nav-head-font">
              <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-mob" id="dropdown-mob-hide">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>My Profile</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit Profile</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>Change Password</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Account Ledger</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sign Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-cus">
  <div class="fixed-nav">
    <div class="fixed-nav-inner open-nav">
      <ul class="text-center">
        <a href="home.html" id="menu-toggle" class="waves-light menu-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i></li>
            <li>Menu</li>
        </a>
        <a href="company.html" class="waves-light">
          <li><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i></li>
          <li>Company</li>
        </a>
        <a href="staff.html" class="waves-light">
          <li><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i></li>
          <li>Staff</li>
        </a>
        <a href="projects.html" class="waves-light">
          <li><i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i></li>
          <li>Projects</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="waves-light">
          <li><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i></li>
          <li>Incidents</li>
        </a>
        <a href="settings.html" class="waves-light">
          <li><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></li>
          <li>Settings</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-sec">
  <div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="mr-3 card-icon-1">
                <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o font-l-1"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body ml-3">
                <h3 class="font-l-1 mb-1">06</h3>
                <span>Projects</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="card-icon-2 mr-3 card-icon-1">
                <i class="fa fa-users font-l-1"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body ml-3">
                <h3 class="font-l-1 mb-1">72</h3>
                <span>Staff</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="card-icon-3 mr-3 card-icon-1">
                <i class="fa fa-universal-access font-l-1"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body ml-3">
                <h3 class="font-l-1 mb-1">10</h3>
                <span>Teams</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card-block">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="card-icon-4 mr-3 card-icon-1">
                <i class="fa fa-user-circle font-l-1"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="media-body ml-3">
                <h3 class="font-l-1 mb-1">5</h3>
                <span>Clients</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is my bootstrap path in my project, I am beginner in codeigniter and php , would appreciate if you can help me **

[image]

Comment: You either add base_url to all your assets or you start them with /. So base_url('foo/bar.css') or src="/foo/bar.css"

Answer (score 2):

change to this `href="<?= base_url('assets/css/yourCSS.css') ?>">`

---

Don't forget to change the configuration in `application/config/config.php` straight to the `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourFolder/';`